# Apply Function With Multiple Arguments to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime, arguments

How to apply a function with multiple arguments to a dataframe? My function is something like this:

```
def test(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    if b == 1 :
        if d == 0 :
            return a-f
    if b == 0 :
        if c == 1 :
            return a-e
```

My sample data is this :

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-29 22:04:000 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2021-04-28 10:10:00 | 2021-04-29 23:14:00 |
| 2021-06-10 06:00:00 | 0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2021-06-09 23:00:00 | 2021-06-11 00:29:00 |
| 2021-06-09 23:00:00 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2021-06-06 11:00:00 | 2021-06-10 06:00:00 |
| 2021-06-06 11:00:00 | 0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2021-06-06 08:00:00 | 2021-06-09 23:00:00 |
| 2021-06-06 08:00:00 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2021-06-06 04:00:00 | 2021-06-06 11:00:00 |

I tried this line of code and then shows error :
the code:

```
df['dt'] = df.apply(test, args=('a','b','c','d','e','f'), axis=1)
```

the error:

```
test() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I don't understand why it detected as 7 arguments when in my code only six.

Comment: The first argument is always populated with row, any values passed as `args` are additional. In this case you've passed the literal characters `a-f` as additional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing your function like so:

```py
def test(row):
    a,b,c,d,e,f = row
    if b == 1 :
        if d == 0 :
            return a-f
    if b == 0 :
        if c == 1 :
            return a-e
```

Then modify the way you apply the function like so:

```py
df['dt'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

Comment: How to apply if the column is not in the same order, have different name, or have other columns between the arguments?

Comment: the names of the columns make no difference since `test()` is unpacking each row into 6 variables. The value of row a will go into variable `a`, the value of row b will go into variable `b`, and so on. @RidwanNurzeha

Comment: so in other words, I must match the order and number of columns between the function and dataframe?

Comment: I just realized I said the wrong thing, I mean to say "The value of **column** a will go into variable a, the value of **column** b, will go into variable b..." etc.
But yes, the number of variables you use to unpack the row must match the order and number of columns in the data frame. @RidwanNurzeha